# Null Navigation In EF 5 code-first

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have an app with Entity Framework 5 code-first this is sample of my classes:

```
public partial class PlaningCourseAssistant 
{
    public PlaningCourseAssistant() {}
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int PlaningCourseID { get; set; }
    public int AssistantID { get; set; }

    public virtual PlaningCourse PlaningCourse { get; set; }
    public virtual Teacher Assistant { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public class Teacher 
{
    public Teacher() 
    {
        ...
        this.PlaningCourseAssistants = new HashSet<PlaningCourseAssistant>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<PlaningCourseAssistant> PlaningCourseAssistants { get; set; }
}
```

And

```
public partial class PlaningCourse 
{
    public PlaningCourse() 
    {
    ...
        this.PlaningCourseAssistants = new HashSet<PlaningCourseAssistant>();
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<PlaningCourseAssistant> PlaningCourseAssistants { get; set; }
}
```

when i add a new object to my `PlaningCourseAssistant` like this :

```
var pcb = new PlaningCourseAssistant 
{
    PlaningCourseID = CourseID,
    AssistantID = assistantID,
};
try 
{
    planingCourseAssistantService.Add(pcb);
    uow.SaveChanges();
} catch { }
```

afterward when i want to get `PlaningCourseAssistant` list, the added `PlaningCourseAssistant`'s `Assistant` navigation key is null.

Why this happen? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF can not lazy load the 'Assistant' property because the `PlaningCourseAssistant` instance you are using is not a proxy created by EF.

You can either use explicit loading

```
context.Entry(pcb).Reference(p => p.Assistant).Load();
context.Entry(pcb.Assistant).Collection(p => p.PlaningCourseAssistant).Load();
```

Or let EF create a proxy instance of `PlaningCourseAssistant`

```
var pcb = context.PlaningCourseAssistants.Create();
```

Comment: @Raika EF creates sub classes of your entities to add logic necessary to lazy load navigational properties. Those are called proxies.

Comment: that `Create` method helps. but if i want use that i need change so many code. is there any way to convert my object to proxy object, without losing any data? i mean i create a `PlaningCourseAssistants` object and fill its data. now i want convert it to proxy object with same data. is that possible?

Comment: @Raika No. You have created a leaky abstraction. You can add a `Create` method to your `uow` which calls the underlying `DbSet.Create`.

Comment: yeah i figure it out by search and testing after my question. its time to changing code. :)).  thank you very much